# jquery functions wont work on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click, toggle

im new here.
    I have a problem with JQUERY. It wont work on 1st click but works on every other click as intended.

I have 4 scripts here:

1st toggles div height between 400px and 60px,
2nd toggles line height so the text moves with div height,
3rd toggles text,
4th toggles background.

On my computer it works normally on second click as click. First click doesnt do anything.

On fiddle you can see that it toggles text on first click and bugs out.

```js
$("#map-cover").click((function() {
    var i = 0;
    return function(){
        $(this).animate({height:(++i % 2) ? 400 : 60},{ duration: 200, queue: false });
    
    }
})());
 $("#map-cover").click((function() {
    var i = 0;
    return function(){
        $(this).animate({lineHeight:(++i % 2) ? 400 : 60},{ duration: 200, queue: false });
        
    }
})()); 
 
$('.background').click(function ()
{
    return $(this).is('.background')
    ?
        $(this).css('background', 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.9)').removeClass('background')
    :
        $(this).css('background', 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.4)').addClass('background')
    ;
});

    
$("#map-cover").on("click", function(){
    if($(this).text()=="OPEN THE MAP")
    {
        $(this).text("CLOSE THE MAP");
    } else {
        $(this).text("OPEN THE MAP");
    }
    $(".ISProductBody").toggle(); 

    return false;
});
```

```css
.background {
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
}
.background-alt {
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
   
}

#map-cover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background" id="map-cover">OPEN THE MAP</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with `var i = 1;`

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/atywustc/)

**EDIT**: See Barmar's answer for the explanation since I  can't do it better than him. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified your code and corrected a bunch of issues (mostly to do with readability and maintainability).

But the issue comes down to how you're checking the value of `(++i % 2)` where you need to compare against `(++i % 2 === 0)`.

But as you're going to be check the value of the incremented `i` twice, it is better to increment separately of the comparison then just compare the value of `i % 2` against `0`

```js
var open, i = 0;
$("#map-cover").click(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    if(!open) {
        open = true;
        self.addClass('background');
        self.text("CLOSE THE MAP");
    } else {
        open = false;
        self.removeClass('background');
        self.text("OPEN THE MAP");
    }
    $(this).animate(
        { 
            'height': (!(i % 2 === 0) ? 400 : 60),
            'line-height': (!(i % 2 === 0) ? 400 : 60)
        },
        { 
            duration: 200, 
            queue: false 
        }
    );
    $(".ISProductBody").toggle();
    i++; 
});
```

```css
#map-cover {
  background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}
#map-cover.background {
  background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map-cover">OPEN THE MAP</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first click is setting `height` and `lineHeight` to the same values that they have in the CSS. The initial value of `i` is `0`. The value of `++i` is `1`, `1 % 2` is `1`, which is truthy, so on the first click the value of `(++i % 2) ? 400 : 60` is `400`.

Just change the order of the values there, or use `i++` instead of `++i`.

```js
$("#map-cover").click((function() {
  var i = 0;
  return function() {
    $(this).animate({
      height: (i++ % 2) ? 400 : 60
    }, {
      duration: 200,
      queue: false
    });

  }
})());
$("#map-cover").click((function() {
  var i = 0;
  return function() {
    $(this).animate({
      lineHeight: (i++ % 2) ? 400 : 60
    }, {
      duration: 200,
      queue: false
    });

  }
})());

$('.background').click(function() {
  return $(this).is('.background') ?
    $(this).css('background', 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.9)').removeClass('background') :
    $(this).css('background', 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.4)').addClass('background');
});


$("#map-cover").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "OPEN THE MAP") {
    $(this).text("CLOSE THE MAP");
  } else {
    $(this).text("OPEN THE MAP");
  }
  $(".ISProductBody").toggle();

  return false;
});
```

```css
.background {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
.background-alt {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#map-cover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background" id="map-cover">OPEN THE MAP</div>
```